# Which python argument type would be accepted as char* in python C extension

Tags: python, swig

I wrote a simple Python extension using C++ like:

```
class Foo
{
   public:
     void Test(char* inbuffer);
};
```

I used the Swig to generate wrapper in the extension.

But I failed to test this function by either passing the string or bytes array like

```
myobj= foo.Foo()
keydata = "abcd"
myobj.Test(keydata)
```

I got errors as:

> TypeError: in method 'Test', argument 2 of type 'char *'

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Show us more details. Now it is not clear, what happens.

Comment: Is the `char*` a pointer to a null terminated string? Does the function modify it? If not, why isn't it `const char *`?

Answer (score 1):

You would need a typemap. Instead, you should use the STL classes whenever possible as they map better to Python types. For instance, use `std::string` instead of `char*`, via `%include std_string.i`:

```
%include "std_string.i"

class Foo
{
   public:
     void Test(std::string inbuffer);
};
```

Note: there probably is no performance gain in using `const std::string&` because the wrapper has to do a copy from Python string to C++ string either way.

Answer (score 0):

Your post does not contain enough information.  For example, this works using SWIG 2.0.12, Visual Studio 2012 and Python 3.3.  Maybe this full example will help you figure out your issue.

#### foo.i

```
%module foo

%inline %{
#include <stdio.h>
class Foo {
public:
    void Test(char* inbuffer) {
        printf("%s\n",inbuffer);
    }
};
%}
```

#### Build

```
swig -c++ -python foo.i
cl /LD /Ic:\python33\include /Fe_foo.pyd foo_wrap.cxx -link /libpath:c:\python33\libs
```

#### Output

```
Python 3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 10:35:05) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import foo
>>> f=foo.Foo()
>>> f.Test('abc')
abc
```